# Is there any way to set vertical alignment in css?

Tags: css

Is there any way to set vertical alignment in css? I have a text inside my `<li>` element, But when I set my text align to centre, it only set the horizontal alignment of the text. But when I use the padding-top function, it change the size of the `<li>` element.So how can i set the vertical alignment without changing the size of my `<li>` element?

Comment: Look up the `vertical-align` property.

Comment: @paddy: This does not do what you think it does. depot's answer is the sure way to do this (as long as the text does not wrap).

Comment: Oh, maybe *I* should look it up then =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adjusting the `line-height` of the `li`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to adjust any spacing, I'd suggest:

```
li {
     position: relative;
     top: 2px;
}
```

This will adjust the vertical position relative to the list item's height, without adjusting the size of the element.